# for loop iteration makes method return wrong values

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am interested in modeling the trading strategy so I tried to use python to simulate the strategy. I wrote this from scratch and there are a few problems when I run it.

```
def strategy(strain, date, cash, holding):
    def order(strain, amount, date, cash, holdling):
        cash[date]=cash[date-1] - strain[date-1]*amount
        holding[date]=holding [date-1] + amount
        return
    amount = int(cash[0]*0.1/strain[date-1])
    cash.append(cash[date-1])
    holding.append(holding[date-1])
    if (#some strategy) : order(strain, amount, date, cash, holding) 
    return cash, holding
def main():
    cash = [1000000,1000000]
    holding = [0,0]
    total = []
    new = #an array of time series data  
    day = len(new)
    Time = np.arange(2, day-20, 1)
    for j in np.arange(2, day-20, 1):
        **cash, holding = strategy (new, j, cash, holding)**  
        count =  cash[j-1] + holding[j-1]*new[j-1]
        count = count/1000000
        total.append(count)
    plt.plot(Time, total, 'r', label='return')        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I use `cash` and `holding` lists to store the buying power left and the shares I am holding. `total` list is used to store the return. As I define in strategy method, I first append a new element in `cash` and `holding` to be the same as previous one, and if the signal to order is triggered order method will be called and the new element will be replaced. However after I ran the code, `cash` and `total` will somehow drop back to the initial value 1000000 and 1, even though I never intended to set them.

Is there something wrong with `cash, holding = strategy (new, j, cash, holding)`?

[image: the plot]

Comment: This is way more code to read and understand than can be expected from volunteers. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with a concrete question.

Comment: There is a problem you are not returning anything fro. `order` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `order` function you were passing the arguments and modifying them but wasn't returning them that is why no change was reflected on holding even when `cash` was updated with a new element.

```
def strategy(strain, date, cash, holding):
    def order(strain, amount, date, cash, holdling):
        cash[date]=cash[date-1] - strain[date-1]*amount
        holding[date]=holding [date-1] + amount
        return cash, holding
    amount = int(cash[0]*0.1/strain[date-1])
    cash.append(cash[date-1])
    holding.append(holding[date-1])
    if (#some strategy) :. 
        cash, holding = order(strain, amount, date, cash, holding) 
    return cash, holding
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help!